# How is overflow_stack variable included in entry.S in arm64 architecture?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, assembly, arm64

The `overflow_stack` variable is used in the `kernel_ventry` macro in [arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.8/arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S#L106)

```
    /* Switch to the overflow stack */
    adr_this_cpu sp, overflow_stack + OVERFLOW_STACK_SIZE, x0
```

It seems to me to be declared in [arch/arm64/include/asm/stacktrace.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.8/arch/arm64/include/asm/stacktrace.h#L110)

```
DECLARE_PER_CPU(unsigned long [OVERFLOW_STACK_SIZE/sizeof(long)], overflow_stack);
```

However, this header file is not included in entry.S, or in any other meaningful header that I can find. Is there another way it is being included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no other way; `overflow_stack` isn’t declared or defined in any header included by `entry.S`. But that’s not an error [as far as the assembler is concerned](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.35/as/Symbol-Attributes.html#Symbol-Attributes); `overflow_stack` doesn’t have a local prefix, so it ends up as an undefined symbol in `arch/arm64/kernel/entry.o`, which is resolved when the kernel is linked.

Run

```
make arch/arm64/kernel/entry.o
```

(or `make CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- ARCH=arm64 arch/arm64/kernel/entry.o` on an architecture other than `arm64`); then

```
objdump -t arch/arm64/kernel/entry.o
```

will show (among others)

```
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 overflow_stack
```

The relocation tables include an number of entries for `overflow_stack+0x0000000000001000` (`overflow_stack + OVERFLOW_STACK_SIZE`); run `objdump -r arch/arm64/kernel/entry.o` to see them.

Comment: I see - I can recreate simplified analogous scenarios with assembly, but not in C. GCC always complains about undeclared identifiers. Is there a special flag you know of that would allow for undeclared identifier in C?

Comment: I’ve added some more context. The assembler handles undeclared symbols as untyped symbols with no attributes; C on the other hand requires symbols to be typed, which means they must be declared. I’m not aware of a flag to change that.